# ImageView request layout being called unnecessarily when it's bounds are fixed

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-glide

So I've come across this method in ImageView for setting drawable...in which if the latest drawable bounds are not same as previous drawable bounds requestLayout is being called...but shouldn't there be an extra check if the image view bounds are not fixed (eg: 80 dp x 80dp) only then requestLayout...since i've a recycler view and am using Glide for downloading images... requestLayout of recycler view is being called particular child image view drawable is being set when Glide completes the download..

```
public void setImageDrawable(@Nullable Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mUri = null;

        final int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
        final int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

        updateDrawable(drawable);

        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

So why would image view request layout when it's drawable is changing even in case if i had specified a fixed bounds (80x80) for it ?

Comment: What use case? You need to be more clear about what your problem is. If the new image is the same size as the previous one, requestLayout() isn't called because it doesn't need to change.

Comment: So since i'm asking Glide to download image after an image view is laid out...and once it completes download it will call setImageDrawable which in turn is calling requestLayout again...if the view is being recycled then there wouldn't be any issues since previous drawable and current drawable will be of same size..but for the first time when image view is laid out and Glide is downloading the image in parallel..this happens

Comment: If there is no drawable set, oldWidth and mDrawableWidth (and height) will be zero, so it won't requestLayout.

Comment: If there is no initial drawable set mDrawableWidth & mDrawableHeight are defaulted to -1, now let's say Glide downloaded the image and called setImageDrawable...now oldWidth, oldHeight are -1 but newWidth, newHeight are 80dp so clearly it would call requestLayout...

Comment: OK... so what's the problem with that? It's calling requestlayout after you set a Drawable for the first time. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: But the question is why would the image bounds change if i've clearly set a fixed width, height for it...changing the drawable should only requestLayout if image view bounds are wrap_content...so if there's a check for comparing old & new drawables bounds..why isn't there an extra check if the image view bounds are already fixed ??

Comment: Oh, why didn't you just say that? ;) Because requestlayout should be called when something has has invalidated the view - not just when its size has changed. Are you having lag issues or something?

Comment: Yes...since i kept a debug point on requestLayout in RecyclerView and checked when it's being called on scroll...and i found this

Comment: But..if requestLayout is being called to invalidate the view then why is there a check for old and new drawable bounds...it should've always requested for layout ??

Comment: This is definitely not the reason your app is lagging. The reason for the lag will be in some code that you wrote, not the ImageView class.

Comment: I agree..but unnecessary requestLayout calls are not what i'm expecting..i created a copy paste code of ImageView class for trial purpose and kept an extra check if bounds are fixed not to requestLayout...now these unnecessary calls are not happening

Comment: I am facing the same problem. And the lag is especially huge in case if GridView is used. And there is no possibility to use RecyclerView because of legacy code.